# int is incompatible with xml SQL server

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I have a problem with the query I am trying to implement in my `.net` code

Here is the query I need to implement:

Operand type clash: int is incompatible with xml

```
DECLARE
    @TABLE_VALUES AS TABLE(
        [KEY] VARCHAR(MAX),
        VALUE VARCHAR(MAX)
    );

    DECLARE  
    @rept_sp_name VARCHAR(50),
    @TABLE_VALUES_xml INT



    SELECT @rept_sp_name =  REPT_SP_NAME FROM SREPTEM WHERE REPT_TRACK_ID = @rept_track_id

    print @rept_sp_name

    SET @TABLE_VALUES_xml = (SELECT * FROM @TABLE_VALUES FOR XML RAW)

    print 'hola mundo'

    EXEC @rept_sp_name @params, @TABLE_VALUES_xml OUT

    print 2

END 
GO
```

Comment: `DECLARE  
    @rept_sp_name VARCHAR(50),
    @TABLE_VALUES_xml INT`  shouldnt that be XML instead of INT

Comment: Both `VALUE` and `KEY` are reserved words in SQL -- why use these as column names?

Comment: side note, you have an `END` and no `BEGIN` so that's going to throw a syntax error...